# i want to fetch product_description but it contain html so i m getting confuse that how to get proper format from it

Tags: ios, json, swift

JSON:

```
{ "wishlist": [ { "wishlist": 0 } ], "cart": [ { "cart": 1 } ], "product": [ { "promo_id": 0, "avals": 0, "dis": null, "mp_product_id": 252, "mp_category_id": 113, "product_name": "Pink Soft Net Fabric Kids Angel Lehenga Choli", "product_description": "
This Pink Coloured Traditional Soft Net  Fabric Lehenga Choli gives a beautifull look to  your child. This Outfit come with Brocket Fabric Lehenga and Top has Soft Net Fabric with Silk Lining come along with Soft Net Dupatta .\r\n\r\n

You can make your kids wear this outfit for parties and functions.\r\n\r\n

Type :\r\n\r\n

*Semi-Stitched*\r\n\r\n

FABRIC :\r\n\r\n

Top : Unstitched Designer Brocade fabric
\r\nBottom : stitched Soft Net fabric
\r\nDupatta : Soft Net fabric
\r\nInner : Silk fabric\r\n\r\n

Size Chart :\r\n\r\n

1 to 5 year : 30 inches
\r\n6 to 8 year : 32 inches
\r\n9 to 10 year : 34 inches
\r\n10 to 15 year: 36 inches\r\n\r\n

Care 
\r\nDry Clean\r\n", "sku_number": "Angel_3_Pink", "qty": 25, "likes_count": 0, "list_price": 2082, "selling_price": 1249, "discount": 41 } ], "image": [ { "image_name": "Sweet Angel Vol3-Pink.jpg" } ], "variant": [ { "Color": "PINK", "Size": "S,M,L,XL", "Occasion": "Party" } ], "related": [ { "mp_product_id": 231, "mp_category_id": 113, "product_name": "White Peacock Kids Indo Western ", "product_description": "

This White Coloured Traditional Banglory Top Fabrics Indo Western  gives a beautifull look to  your child. This Outfit come with Paper Silk Fabric Lehenga and Top has Banglory  Fabric.\r\n\r\n

You can make your kids wear this outfit for parties and functions.\r\n\r\n

Type :\r\n\r\n

*Stitched*\r\n\r\n

FABRIC :\r\n\r\n

Top - Banglory (foam seat work),\r\n\r\n

Lehenga - Paper silk,\r\n\r\n

Size Chart :\r\n\r\n

6 to 12 year : 34 inches\r\n\r\n

Care 
\r\nDry Clean\r\n", "product_image": "", "seller_product_code": "White_Peacock", "system_product_code": 0, "sku_number": "White_Peacock", "status": "A", "is_features": 0, "list_price": 2271, "selling_price": 1249, "qty": 25, "weight": "700", "cod_charge": "0", "shipping_charge": "0", "likes_count": 0, "create_date": "2017-06-26 12:38:51", "modify_date": "2017-06-26 12:39:37", "main_order": 14, "set_order": 0, "image_name": "Peacock White Kids \u00a0--- CKL 216 --- Rs. 625.jpg" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are doing the same thing, but your code is prone to crashes as you are forcefully trying to unwrap optionals. Try this instead

```
Alamofire.request(APIProductDetail, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let responseResultValue):
            if let responseResult = responseResultValue as? [String:Any] {
                if let productsList = responseResult["product"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for product in productsList {
                        if let productDescription = product["product_description"] as? String {
                            print(productDescription)  //Here you will get the product description
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        case .failure(let error):
            //handle any error here
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
```

Comment: sir, i am using almofire to call json my code looks like this 
 Alamofire.request(APIProductDetail, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON
            { (response) in
                
                self.result = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                let Str2 = self.result.value(forKey: "product")as! NSArray
                let Product_Description = (Str2.object(at: 0) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "product_description") as! String
}

Comment: @user8198079, I've updated my code with Alamofire. You have done the same thing. Please try above